# AJAX not taking value from input text field to mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I have an input field where the user types in a name and it auto populates so they can choose from it. This is retrieved from mysql fine.

However, I want it so that when they press submit, the value is queried in mysql to return corresponding information based on the input value.

I'm using the ajax method so that the page doesn't refresh. The problem is that it seems that the AJAX is passing on a blank value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>test</title>
   </head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <body>
      <!-- code for autocomplete -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {

             //autocomplete
             $(".auto").autocomplete({
                 source: "search.php",
                 minLength: 1
             });                

         });
      </script>
      <header class="s-header header">
         <div class="parent">
            <!-- empty for now -->
         </div>
      </header>
      <!-- the form that I'm using which has 1 input -->
      <section>
         <form id="myForm">
            <label>City:</label>
            <input type="text" name="auto" class="auto" id="auto">
            <input type="button" value="Find" id="submit">
         </form>
      </section>
      <!-- using this to output what I get from mysql-->
      <div id="output" class="output"></div>
   </body>
   <script>
      if (window.history.replaceState ) {
          window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
      }
   </script>
   <!-- AJAX to POST to mysql -->
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {       

       //if submit button is clicked

      $('#submit').click(function () {       



        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
          //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
          url: "return.php",

          //POST method is used
          type: "post",

          //pass the data        
          data: $("#myForm").serialize(),

          //success
          success: function (d) {
          alert(d);      
          var id = d;  
            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
              $('#output').html(id); //Set output element html      
          }      
        });

        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
      });
      }); 

   </script>
</html>
```

Code for return.php (file that takes ajax post)

```
<?php 


    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $q = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["auto"]);

    $sql = $connection->query("SELECT Postal Code FROM databasename WHERE Name = '$q'");

    if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {

      while ($data = $sql->fetch_array()) 
        echo "<h2 class='animatedText'>Doctor located in: ".$data['Points'] . "</h2>"; 

    }
    else
      echo $q;


?>
```

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)` and check the `alert ` message. I recommend using `console.log` for debugging as `alert` may not give you the correct output (especially when debugging `object`s).

Comment: thanks @ths I Assume var_dump($_POST) is var=dump($_POST)?
Where would i put console.log?

Comment: no it's as it is `var_dump($_POST)`, put it instead of the `alert` in your code.

Comment: thanks, so it seems like the problem is not with my POST but rather with my SQL statement - I will input the code for the .php containing mysql statements

Comment: All your `<script>` tags should be within either `<head>` or `<body>`. One of yours exists in the badlands between `</body>` and `</html>`